# C++ type slot argument not supported

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I'm trying to emit a signal and send two parameters, one is a list of `Song` objects, and the second is a `QtGui.QTableView` object.

I tried doing that:

```
self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("searchOutput(list, QtGui.QTableView)"), songsObjs, self.table)
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: C++ type 'list' is not supported as a slot argument type
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a look at the [reference](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/old_style_signals_slots.html#the-pyqt-pyobject-signal-argument-type) then it says

> It is possible to pass any Python object as a signal argument by specifying PyQt_PyObject as the type of the argument in the signature.

and

> While this would normally be used for passing objects like lists and dictionaries as signal arguments, it can be used for any Python type.

So try instead to do this:

```
self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("searchOutput(PyQt_PyObject, QtGui.QTableView)"), songsObjs, self.table)
```